# Есть ли api для проверки видео с музыкой, на авторские права?

Tags: api, авторские-права, музыка

Надо через API проверить авторские права на музыку (а лучше видео с музыкой), передавая файл с данными, желательно через API в сервис, который может определить, если ли авторские права на музыкальном произведении. Может знаете похожие сервисы или есть решение. Раньше YouTube давал API  и можно было проверить, теперь нельзя у них это сделать.
Заранее, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Авторские права есть всегда по умолчанию. Более того, по российским законом автор в принципе не может отказаться от авторских прав

Comment: @andreymal, термин "авторские права" во множественном числе означает что их несколько. Неотчуждаемы только право на авторство и право на имя. Имущественные же права вполне отчуждаемы, в некоторых случаях даже автоматически. Вопрос очевидно об исключительном праве.

Answer (score 2):

Решили пойти обходным путем:

1. Извлечет из полученного видео-файла аудио дорожку
2. По SDK Shazam или другого аналогичного, сервиса определит автора и название трека
3. Проверит трек по базе https://eproves.com/ о наличии у музыкального произведения авторских прав и выдаст результат о типе лицензии по которой распространяется данное произведение

Comment: Могли обратится к нам в контакты на eProves - мы бы дали развернутый ответ.